# How can I use a relation in the where of a sequelize query?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql, sequelize.js

I have two tables let's call them 'person' and 'car' with the below relation. A Person can have 1 or 0 cars. in the latter case there will be no entry in the Car table.

```
Person:
  firstName,
  lastName,
  ....
  hasOne(Car, {
    foreignKey: 'personId',
    as: 'personsCar'
  })
```

```
Car:
  personId,
  colour,
  ...
  belongsTo(Person, {
    foreignKey: 'personId',
    as: 'carOwner'
  })
```

Using Sequelize I want to get all the people with **either a 'green' car or no car** from the Person table

Just attempting to get people with any colour car with the below gives the error "column Person.personsCar does not exist", how can I correctly reference a relation in the where of a query?

```
Person.findAll({
  include: [
    model: Car,
    as: 'personsCar',
    attributes: ['colour'],
  ],
  where: {
    personsCar: {
      [op.eq]: null,
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in this way :

```
Person.findAll({
    include: [
        model: Car,
        as: 'personsCar',
        attributes: ['colour'],
        where: {
            colour : 'green' // <---- YOUR COLOUR
        },
    ],
})
```

Comment: Thanks Vivek! this is the exact answer for what I asked, but I missed an important criteria I want to get People who have no car as well.